# JavaFX Maven Plugin Failed to execute goal (missing parameters)

Tags: maven, javafx, netbeans-8

I use below `pom.xml` file to package my JavaFX 8 application. When I run through NetBeans I get following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project CoperativeERP: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>re.iprocu</groupId>
<artifactId>CoperativeERP</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CoperativeERP</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>re.iprocu.coperativeerp.MainApp</mainClass>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Your Organisation</name>
</organization>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                                <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using `jdk 1.8.0_77` with NetBean IDE 8.1.

I am new to Maven and JavaFX packaging, so am expecting something easy to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
<configuration>
   <mainClass></mainClass>
</configuration>
```

It is empty. There you main class fully specified name (example `com.myproject.Main`) should be written.

Looking at [documentation](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) whole plug-in configuration should looks like this:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>8.5.0</version>
   <configuration>
       <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
       <mainClass>your.package.with.Launcher</mainClass>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Make sure that your `<mainClass>` contains main method (apps entry point) and tat you are using newest version possible. Also try first build the project by `mvn clean package` without the `javafx-maven-plugin`.

Comment: I updated that by adding the main class, still error persist